# $y''-2y'+y=te^t$ by method of undetermined coefficients

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In order to solve

$$y''-2y'+y=te^t$$ I did:

$$y = (at+b)e^t\implies\\ y' = ate^t+ae^t+be^t\implies \\y''= ate^t+2ae^t+be^t$$

but when I put these in the differential equation I'm getting zeros eveywhere. Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case you need to look for a solution in the form 
$$
(At+B)t^2e^t.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your auxiliary equation is $\lambda^2-2\lambda+1=0$, which has the repeated root $\lambda=1$.

Because there is a repeated root, the general solution to the homogeneous d.e. $y''-2y'+y=0$ is $y=Ae^t+Bte^t$.

When you consider the non-homogeneous part, you will see that the RHS takes the same form as the general solution, so is no good as a particular integral.

Try $y=Ct^2e^t$

$y'=Ct^2e^t+2tCe^t$

$y''=Ct^2e^t+2tCe^t+2tCe^t+2Ce^t=Ct^2e^t+4tCe^t+2Ce^t$

d.e. says that $y''-2y'+y=te^t$

So $Ct^2e^t+4tCe^t+2Ce^t-2(Ct^2e^t+2tCe^t)+Ct^2e^t=te^t$

We get $2Ce^t=te^t$ which doesn't work...

OK, ramp it a step further and try $y=Dt^3e^t$

$y'=Dt^3e^t+3t^2De^t$

$y''=Dt^3e^t+3t^2De^t+3t^2De^t+6tDe^t=Dt^3e^t+6t^2De^t+6tDe^t$

d.e. says that $y''-2y'+y=te^t$

So $Dt^3e^t+6t^2De^t+6tDe^t-2(Dt^3e^t+3t^2De^t)+Dt^3e^t=te^t$

$6tDe^t=te^t$

$D=\frac 16$

The general solution is $y=Ae^t+Bte^t+\frac 16 t^3e^t$

Now what boundary conditions or initial conditions do you have?

Comment: wait, should I try $y = Ct^2e^t$ or $y = (A+Bt+Ct^2)e^t$?

Comment: Put $y=Ct^2e^t$ into the differential equation and get yourself a value for $C$. Then the general solution will be $y=(A+Bt+Ct^2)e^t$. To find A and B you will need some boundary conditions.

Comment: from that I get c = 0

Comment: http://bit.ly/2epeoRb

Comment: are you sure thsi is the method? Also, how do you know what to do when you know that the function to the right of the equation is already a solution? Using $t^2$ seemed arbitrary to me

Comment: I'd try $y = (at^2+bt+c)e^t$ and find $a,b,c$

Comment: I know it looks arbitrary, but we're trying functions that differentiate to give $te^t$. That just has to be something like $t^ne^t$. We can't use $y=e^t$ ($n=0$) and $y=te^t$ ($n=1$) so we try higher powers of $n$ until something works. Unfortunately we just get zeroes with $y=t^2e^t$ so we go to $n=3$